# connecting from Linux to windows without logging off the current user on windows

Tags: operating-system, remote-desktop, multi-user

what I'm trying to achieve is to log from linux to a windows machine  which is already being used by one user who should not be logged off and the system should be working with both the users simultaneaously .I'm using krdc to connect to windows machine from linux,which logs off the user when other user logs in.Is there any other way to achieve my intension.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the **real** Terminal Services installed. Usually the windows (Home,Professional, etc) can be enabled to have Terminal services but only for a 1 single session. If you install Terminal Services you will need to pay the license for users.

To allow multiple connection you should use VNC/teamviewer (is the most simple way to achieve what you want).

Comment: KRDC does support VNC but it's not able to connect to the server,though rdp is able to connect.

Comment: @pavi, you have to install VNC server on Windows to connect by VNC.

Comment: VNC Server should be installed as separate application, it doesn't come on windows. http://www.tightvnc.com/ http://www.realvnc.com/